# Agoria.io react native apk size issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, agora.io

I have setup  agora.io in my react native app for audio stream but after adding it has increased about 40 mb in apk size as well .ipa.

before it was about 40 but now its more then 80 mb

Comment: There is a same issue on Agora's GitHub page: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/react-native-agora/issues/285, maybe it helps

Comment: for android you can try building aab bundle it can reduce the size drastically.

Comment: Also do not forget to turn on the Hermes Engine: https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes. Enabling Hermes will result in improved start-up time, decreased memory usage, and smaller **app size**

Comment: thanks i will get back to you very soon